# Highlight a word in text in Typescript by using HTML tag

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been trying to use HTML tags inside Typescript to highlight particular words in a sentence before I put these sentence in HTML. I looked for several options in StackOverflow but I could not point to the solution.

The code example is:

```
example.sentences = this.sentences.filter((sentence: { Sentence: string | string[]; }) => sentence.Sentence.includes(word))
        .map((sentence: { Sentence: any; }) => sentence.Sentence.replace(new RegExp(word, 'gi'), match => {
          return `<mark class="marking">${match}</mark>`;
        }));
```

Then I am calling these sentences from HTML:

```
<mark *ngFor="let sentence of example.sentences">
      {{ sentence }}
</mark>
```

The result is:

```
Alice is in <mark class="marking">wonderland</mark>
```

It looks like it is a text in the sentence but not rendered as HTML.

How can I define this in Typescript, or in HTML to change the colour of a word that is in a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You're already returning HTML in your `example.sentences`, I don't think that's necessary. Try it like this:

```js
example.sentences = this.sentences.filter((sentence: { Sentence: string | string[]; }) => sentence.Sentence.includes(word))
        .map((sentence: { Sentence: any; }) => sentence.Sentence.replace(new RegExp(word, 'gi'), match => {
          return match;
        }));
```

```html
<mark *ngFor="let sentence of example.sentences" [innerHTML]="sentence"></mark>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, This is not working since I am trying to mark only a piece of a word but not the whole sentence. Or at least I would like to mark them in a different colour.

Comment: Could you prepare a stackblitz with a minimal working example? I may have misunderstood what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to mark the HTML tags within a string. For example,

```
<div [innerHTML]="sentence"> </div>
```

Comment: changing to [innerHTML] worked. but now, I cannot access the css class that I defined in typescript "marking" through the css file. I put:  .marking {
  background-color: red !important;
} but no function

Comment: By cannot access you mean the class isn't getting added ? Can you add how the code looks now as well as the CSS class ?

Comment: Yes, I mean the CSS does not effect at all. The marking is in default 'yellow' color and this tagging way with innerHTML gives me what I want. However, If I want to change it via css like I shared the example in the above comment, or in the tag `<mark style="background-color=red !important;">${match}</mark>` They do not have any impact.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
// javascript: URLs are dangerous if attacker controlled.
// Angular sanitizes them in data binding, but you can
// explicitly tell Angular to trust this value:
this.dangerousHtml = `<mark class="marking">${match}</mark>`;
this.trustedHtml = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.dangerousHtml);
```